# Fix LS Colors for directories with 777 permission?

Tags: bash, ls, colors

When I run `ls` on a folder with directories that have a 777 permission, the `ls` colors are purple text with a green background, which is unreadable:

[image]

What can I do to make this more pleasant to look at?

Comment: Exactly! Who came up with the terrible idea to combine colors with such low contrast? It's impossible to read

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are using Linux (and not, e.g., using a Mac which does things differently) you can use `dircolors` with a custom database to specify which colors are used for which file attributes.

First, create a dircolors database file.

```sh
$ dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
```

Then edit it, you probably want to change the `STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE` and `OTHER_WRITABLE` lines to something more pleasant than `34;42` (34 is blue, 42 is green - `dircolors -p` helpfully includes comments with the color codes listed).

Then run

```sh
eval $(dircolors ~/.dircolors)
```

Edit your ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile etc) and find the line that runs `eval $(dircolors)` and change it to include the filename as above.  Or if there isn't such a line in your .profile (etc) add it.

Or, if you want it to work whether there is a `~/.dircolors` file or not, change it to:

```sh
[ -e ~/.dircolors ] && eval $(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors) || 
    eval $(dircolors -b)
```

Comment: BTW, if you edit the .dircolors file with `vim` then vim's syntax highlighting will show you colours as you edit them.

Comment: Is there a reason I should do do eval instead of just copying/pasting the result into my .bashrc?

Comment: assuming you mean the output of `dircolors -b` and not `dircolors -p` (which isn't sh code): 1. to avoid bloating your .bashrc   2. so you can just edit `~/.dircolors` rather than the far-less-readable output of `dircolors -b`.

Comment: There is a nice wiki showing all the color options. If you want to remove the background color, just remove ";42" is enough

Answer (score 0):

As a stopgap solution, you can use `ls --color=never`.  (Works on CentOS, not sure about `ls` options on Cygwin; check `man ls` if it doesn't work.)

Also type `alias`, and if you see `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`, you can run `unalias ls` to turn off automatic coloring of `ls` output.  More permanent solutions (i.e. actually changing those colors instead of removing them) involve changing the colorization options for your terminal, but I'll leave that answering job for someone who actually knows how to do it....