# How to turn off the color in my $PS1?

Tags: bash, colors

The output in my terminal contains many colors,i want to show all characters only in white color on my black background .

```
echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Do as choroba say that to remove `the \[\033..\] parts`,it is no use:

```
vim .bashrc
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"
```

Now source it :

```
source  .bashrc
```

Check with `ls /tmp`:

[image]

Just to keep character color white,other setting remains unchanged.

Comment: `ls` is not `bash`, and the settings of one to use colors are not the same as the settings for the other to use colors. Similarly for all other programs that might or might not use them, e.g. any editor. (Note that you asked specifically about `$PS1`.) Of course there's heavy hammers like changing the settings of your terminal emulator to show everything in black and white, or possibly changing `TERM` to some terminal that doesn't even support colors and hoping the programs actually obey that (which won't help with any hard-coded escapes sequences in `PS1`)

Comment: You have to fix your terminal emulator -- everything else is pointless. Each and every program will need a separate workaround (`export GCC_COLORS=` will not do for `clang`, and for most python craplets simply there's NO workaround -- they assume that everybody wants colors, that the background is always black,  and that any terminal supports colors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `\[\033..\]` parts. These are the ANSI colour codes.

The initial `\[\e]0;...` is similar, but it sets the terminal title.

Comment: The output for `ls /tmp` still contain colors!

Comment: You probably have `$LS_COLORS` in effect or you aliased `ls` to `ls --color=auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating two entirely separate and unrelated things: bash's prompt string (`PS1`) and the colours optionally used by `ls`.

1. I also like a very simple prompt with no colour codes (and I have no need for special handling of chroots), so I have just:

   ```
    PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
   ```

   You'll need to change this setting in your current shell(s) and in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` or wherever else it may be set.
2. To remove colours from the output of `ls`, get rid of any aliases for `ls` which add the `--colors=` option (or change it to `--colors=never`), and comment out or delete any statements like `eval dircolors` or which set the `LS_COLORS` variable.

   Again, this needs to be done in both the current shell(s) and in the shell startup scripts.

   `~/.bash_aliases` is often used for defining aliases as well as, or instead of, the startup scripts mentioned above.
3. Alternatively, to **change** the colours used by `ls` (dark blue on black is unreadable garbage - a terrible default), change the `LS_COLORS` variable.  e.g. see my answer to [Fix LS Colors for directories with 777 permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241735/7696)

Answer (score -1):

Remove color setting in ls command:

```
vim .bashrc
alias  ls="ls --color=never"
```

Comment: But your question was about changing the colors in the PS1 prompt, not in the output of ls.

Comment: this will remove color from `ls`'s output, but you'll still get from other program (e.g. `grep foo sample.ttx`). you'll have to work on terminal level.