# How to do pattern matching on `.bashrc` for file extensions

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards

I'm modifying my `.bashrc`: I want to make it so that `.zip`,`.tar` and `.tar.gz` files (and maybe more later down the road) are shown with a red color. Thing is, I want to match for all those files once. So on the `.bashrc` file I have:

```
LS_COLORS='*.hs=35:*.py=93:*.[zip|tar.*]=31'
export LS_COLORS
```

If possible, I would like to avoid

```
LS_COLORS='*.hs=35:*.py=93:*.zip=31:*.tar=31:*.tar.gz=31'
export LS_COLORS
```

However, my method is not working. What should I modify?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with `LSCOLORS`, that's its own syntax. We could help you generate the full string, I guess, but it's probably easier, faster and simpler to just write it out.

Comment: Really? How strange, I would've guessed that had to be feature.That's a bit shame. 
Thanks for the reply! Btw, does `*.tar.*` work? (as in everything before .tar and everything after).  Because it is not working for me

Comment: I don't know how `ls` handles these internally, but `*.tar.*` might work since it is a standard, portable globbing pattern. `[zip|tar.*]` is not. Also note that these are _not_ regular expressions, they are glob patterns. `*.hs` would be invalida as a regex since the `*` means "0 or more of the preceding character" and there is no preceding character there.

Comment: It doesn't work! How strange

Comment: Remember that this is all handled internally by `ls`, it isn't using the shell so it makes perfect sense that `ls` has its own internal language. Oh, and although you probably don't need to `export` at all, you certainly don't need to do it on two lines and can just `export LS_COLORS='*.hs=35:*.py=93:*.zip=31:*.tar=31:*.tar.gz=31'`.

Comment: Thank you much @terdon! Do you want to write that down as the answer so I can mark it as finished?

Comment: Create/edit and use `~/.dircolors` file.  see, e.g. my answer to [Fix LS Colors for directories with 777 permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241735).  And search for other questions & answers on this site that mention `LS_COLORS` and/or `dircolors`.  BTW, like any other plain-text config file it's easy to generate some or all of it with scripts, it's just text after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but I suspect that this isn't possible since this is all about the way that `ls` itself handles whatever value you store in `LS_COLORS`. So unless they have chosen to implement what you describe, it won't be possible and you will need to bite the bullet and write it all out. At least you can do it on one line instead of two:

```
export LS_COLORS='*.hs=35:*.py=93:*.zip=31:*.tar=31:*.tar.gz=31'
```

You can also avoid the need to type it all out by using a trick like this:

```
$ printf '*.%s=31:' {zip,tar,tar.gz,tgz,Z,xz,7z}
*.zip=31:*.tar=31:*.tar.gz=31:*.tgz=31:*.Z=31:*.xz=31:*.7z=31:
```

And then you just need to copy/paste it once.